# How to get the values of an array retrieved from database in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a code with me to get the values from the database in an array as shown below :

```
  $uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);
  $student_id='S17AB21017';

  $data['profile_data']=$this->studentsmodel->get_Cinprofile($student_id);


  $pay = $this->instamojo->pay_request( 

                    $amount = "6930" , 
                    $purpose = "Primary Colors Internationals" , 
                    $buyer_name = "Apple" , 
                    $email = "webteam6@marrs.in" , 
                    $phone = "7034805760" ,
                    $send_email = 'TRUE' , 
                    $send_sms = 'TRUE' , 
                    $repeated = 'FALSE'

                );
```

I want to get the values in `$data` values for `$buyer_name`,`$email` and `$phone` and give it in the pay_request(). The values for name,email and phone is obtained from the table `students_to_cin`.How can I get the values ?

The code for `get_Cinprofile()` is shown below :

```
 public function get_Cinprofile($student_id)
 {
   //echo $student_id;die;
     $this->db->select('students_to_cin.*,schools.school_name,schools.school_address,schools.school_address1,schools.school_email,schools.school_phone,schools.school_principal_name,schools.school_medium,states.state_subdivision_name,class.class_key,category.categoryKey,period.period_name,countries.country_name,studentlist.stud_cin,studentlist.stud_syllabus,studentlist.stud_school_state,studentlist.stud_school_country,schools.school_pincode');
    $this->db->from('students_to_cin');
    $this->db->join('schools','schools.school_id=students_to_cin.school_id');
    $this->db->join('states','states.state_subdivision_id=students_to_cin.state_id');
    $this->db->join('class','students_to_cin.class_id = class.class_id'); /*class.class_key,*/
    $this->db->join('category','students_to_cin.category_id = category.category_id');
    $this->db->join('period','students_to_cin.period_id = period.period_id');
    $this->db->join('countries','students_to_cin.country_id = countries.country_id');
    $this->db->join('studentlist','students_to_cin.cin = studentlist.stud_cin');

    $this->db->where('students_to_cin.student_id',$student_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();//echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
    $result = $query->row_array(); 

    return $result;

 }
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: you can do like this  : `$profile_data =$this->studentsmodel->get_Cinprofile($student_id); echo $profile_data['name']; echo $profile_data['email'];`

Comment: Ok..It will work rite ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like.....

```
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);
  $student_id='S17AB21017';

  $data['profile_data']=$this->studentsmodel->get_Cinprofile($student_id);


  $pay = $this->instamojo->pay_request( 
                    $amount = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname'] , 
                    $purpose = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname'] , 
                    $buyer_name = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname'] , 
                    $email = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname'] , 
                    $phone = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname'] ,
                    $send_email = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname'] , 
                    $send_sms = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname'] , 
                    $repeated = $data['profile_data']['yourfieldname']
                );
```